# Insert not working

Tags: sql, parameters, sqlcommand, scalar

I've searched evreywhere and tried all suggestions but still no luck when running the following code. Note that some code is commented out. Thats just me trying different things.

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=URB900-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=usersSQL;Integrated Security=True");

```
        string password  = PasswordTextBox.Text;
        string email     = EmailTextBox.Text;
        string firstname = FirstNameTextBox.Text;
        string lastname  = SurnameTextBox.Text;

        //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", username);
        //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);
        //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", email);
        //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstname);
        //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastname);

        command.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        command.Parameters["@UserName"].Value = username;

        command.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        command.Parameters["@Password"].Value = password;

        command.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        command.Parameters["@Email"].Value = email;

        command.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        command.Parameters["@FirstName"].Value = firstname;

        command.Parameters.Add("@LasttName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        command.Parameters["@LasttName"].Value = lastname;

        SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO users (UserName, Password, UserEmail, FirstName, LastName)" +
        "values (@UserName, @Password, @Email, @FirstName, @LastName)", connection);

        connection.Open();
        command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //command2.ExecuteScalar();
        connection.Close();
```

When I run this, fill in the textboxes and hit the button I get......

Must declare the scalar variable "@UserName".

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're attaching the parameters to `command` and then executing a different `command2`

Comment: oops. Thank you for the reply podiluska. I've been struggling for hours with this. Sometimes the answer is staring you right in the face.